# How to use @Factory annotation along with @Guice in a TestNG test class

Tags: testng, guice, factory

I am using `@Guice` annotation for loading my modules like below:

```java
@Guice(modules={MyModule.class})
public class TestITest {

    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int exp;

    @Inject
    ITest iTest;

    public TestITest() {}

    @Factory(dataProvider="get values")
    public TestITest(int a, int b, int exp) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.exp = exp;
    }

    @Test
    public void testITest() {
        assertEquals(iTest.calc(a, b), exp);
    }


    @DataProvider(name="get values")
    public Object[][] getValues() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<Object[]> result = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            int a = rand.nextInt();
            int b = rand.nextInt();
            int exp = a + b;
            result.add(new Object[] {a,b,exp});
        }

        return result.toArray(new Object[result.size()][3]);
    }

}
```

I have created an empty constructor, as `Guice` is complaining about a no argument constructor, I knew adding it won't solve my problem. Then also I added and then another problem arised. All of the ten values are created and TestNG is running the test class with 10 values, but the `ITest` implementation is not being injected and giving me `NullPointerException` 10 times.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem as below (But still I am sure there is another way)

```java
//@Guice(modules={MyModule.class})
public class TestITest {

    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int exp;

    @Inject
    ITest iTest;

       //added a static injector with the module
    public static final Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());

    @Factory(dataProvider="get values")
    public TestITest(int a, int b, int exp) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.exp = exp;

             //Injected implementation here
        injector.injectMembers(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testITest() {
        assertEquals(iTest.calc(a, b), exp);
    }

      // Changed modifier to static
    @DataProvider(name="get values")
    public static Object[][] getValues() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        List<Object[]> result = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            int a = rand.nextInt();
            int b = rand.nextInt();
            int exp = a + b;
            result.add(new Object[] {a,b,exp});
        }

        return result.toArray(new Object[result.size()][3]);
    }

}
```